# How to prefill the fields with static data and get empty section on click using angular2

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

i had made emergency as static data in ts. so now i want that static data to get filled in two section.
Can anyone suggest me how to do or provide any links.
i am very new to reactive forms so please help.

TS:

```
this.emergencyContactForm.patchValue({
  ContactName: this.Emergencies[0].ContactName,
  Phone: this.Emergencies[0].Phone,
  Relationship: this.Emergencies[0].Relationship,
});
      this.emergencyContactForm = this._fb.group({
      itemRows: this._fb.array([this.createItem()])
    });
  }
```

I am not getting how can data be fetched to the field. Please help

Comment: I don't really get what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: in html i want to fetch the static data

Comment: you need to bind the values of emergency to formarray right?

Comment: ya correct thats what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have `emergencies` as an `array`, you should have `multiple formgroup` instances to be in place

For that you should `loop` the `emergencies` and should create `multiple inputs` first

```
this.Emergencies.forEach(
emergency => {
  const control = <FormArray>this.emergencyContactForm.get('itemRows')['controls'];
  control.push(this.createItem());
})

for (let entry in someArray) {
  this.emergencyContactForm.get('itemRows')['controls'][i].patchValue({ 
        ContactName: emergency.ContactName, 
        Phone: emergency.Phone, 
        Relationship: emergency.Relationship, 
      }) 

}
```

this will create `multiple inputs` for number of `elements` in `array` you have

Then in **html** you can use like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 no-padd pt-4" formArrayName="itemRows" *ngFor="let itemrow of emergencyContactForm.get('itemRows').controls;let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i">
   <div>
      <label class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">Contact's Name</label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Contact's Name" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" formControlName="ContactName" 
      />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but i get error for forEach function

Comment: can ypu paste trhe eror?

Answer (score 0):

I can see that your static data is array **'Emergency'** and you are trying to patch form value with **'Emergencies'**.

Comment: sorry, i made it proper in question